# Wann sagt man "physikalisch" und wann "physisch"?

Tags: word-choice

Wann schreibt oder sagt man *physikalisch* und wann *physisch*?

Comment: Hast du es schon mal im Wörterbuch nachgeschlagen? Da gibt's wohl sicher Beispiele, oder?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Physisch* heißt *körperlich*, also alles was irgendwie den Körper betrifft, z.b. die körperliche Verfassung:

> physische Erschöpfung
>   physische Belastung
>   physisch gewalttätig
>   physisch unterlegen

Aber auch materiell, wie [bereits erwähnt](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/8233/23):

> physische Computer (Gegenteil zu virtuellen Maschinen)

*Physikalisch* ist abgeleitet von der Physik und bedeutet, dass es zur Physik gehört:

> physikalisches Experiment
>   physikalisches Gesetz
>   physikalisches Modell
>   physikalisch unmöglich

Comment: Nicht nur „den Körper“ im Sinne von „eigener, menschlicher Körper“, sondern „Körper“ im Allgemeinen. `physische Geographie` betrachtet den Körper Erde im Gegensatz zur `sozialen Geographie`, die den menschlichen Bevölkerungszustand auf der Erde betrachtet.

Answer (score 6):

*Physikalisch* bedeutet "die Physik betreffend", im Sinne der Gesetze und Erkenntnisse der Physik.
Ähnliche Begriffe sind *biologisch*, *chemisch*, *mathematisch*.

*Physisch* ist "den Körper betreffend", auch im Sinne "in der/durch die Natur begründet".
Gegenteilig sind Begriffe wie *mental*, *geistig*, *virtuell*, *seelisch*, *abstrakt*.

Beispiele:
Zwei Dinge können *physisch* nicht an derselben Stelle sein. Das ist naturgegeben körperlich unmöglich.

Ein Ding kann *physikalisch*, laut den Gesetzen der Festkörperphysik, nicht gleichzeitig an zwei verschiedenen Orten sein. Nach der Quantenphysik eventuell schon.

Comment: 1. sind Dinge im Sinn der Festkörperphysik etwas anderes als Dinge im Sinn der Quantenphysik. 2. Können Dinge auch quantenphysikalisch nicht an zwei Orten gleichzzeitig sein. Das würde nämlich bedeuten, dass die integrierte Aufenthaltswahrscheinlichkeit in zwei verschiedenen Gebieten 1 ist.

Answer (score 3):

Physikalisch wenn's was mit Physik zu tun hat, physisch wenn's um etwas Materielles geht.

Comment: Entschuldigung. Geht die Physik nicht manchmal um etwas Materielles?

Comment: Materielles... ist das nicht eher auf den monetären Aspekt bezogen??

Comment: @Vogel612: Ich hätte "körperlich" statt "materiell" gesagt weil letzteres doppeldeutig ist, und seit dem Gebrauch von Buchgeld gerade oft nicht physisch ist.

Comment: @c.p.: Die Frage hilft nicht weiter, weil Materielles, oder körperliches nur ein Teilgebiet der Physik ist. Man denke etwa an Energie, Elektrizität, Magnetismus und an Wellen. Alles nicht physisch aber physikalisch.

Comment: @userunknown ist alles sehr wohl physisch. naja Energie ist ja eigentlich nur ein abstraktes Konzept von Möglichkeiten, Elektrizität ist sich bewegende Elektronen, Magnetismus ist ein Feld, bzw. eine Energie"projektion" die durch ausrichtung von atomen oder elektrischen Strom hervorgerufen wird und Wellen sind nur eine Bewegungsform von Materie.

Comment: @Vogel612: Lichtwellen? Ist der Welle-Teilchen-Dualismus den ich mal gelernt habe Geschichte? http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x9vzh0_olivia-newton-john-lets-get-physica_music Let me hear your body talk! :) Die Energiedefinition weise ich als esoterischen Quark zurück.

Comment: @userunknown dann erkläre das Konzept von Energie mal anders in einem Satz. Außerdem ist der Welle-Teilchen-Dualismus tatsächlich aktuell, aber frei nach e=mc² hat Energie eine Masse und ein Teilchen ist nicht gerade "unkörperlich"

Comment: @Vogel612: Dein Fehler an dieser Stelle ist, dass Du `physisch` behandelst als sei es ein physikalischer Terminus, was es aber gerade nicht ist. Ein einzelnes Teilchen ist auch schwerlich physisch und Energie schon gar nicht. Dazu muss ich auch Energie nicht in einem Satz erklären müssen. Ob ich das kann oder nicht hat mit der Bedeutung der Worte nichts zu tun. Energie als die Fähigkeit Arbeit zu verrichten ist aber nicht schlecht für den Anfang. Du kannst sie nicht anfassen, was man auch über Gase sagen kann, die man aber soweit abkühlen kann, dass sie greifbar werden.

Comment: Wahrheit, Wärme und Witze sind auch nicht physisch - Wärme aber physikalisch.

Comment: @userunknown absoluter Sieg für dich... ich gebe mich geschlagen.

Answer (score 1):

*Physikalisch*, wenn es um Physik geht, *physisch*, wenn es um die Physis geht.

Comment: Neue Fragen: Was ist Physis? Und warum wurde die physische Existenz des Higgs-Bosons nachgewiesen und nicht die physikalische Existenz?

Comment: @chirlu: Eine `physikalische Existenz` würde bedeuten, dass das Higgs-Boson zur wissenschaftlichen Disziplin „Physik“ gehört. Das hat aber niemand bestritten und das wurde auch nicht bewiesen. `physische Existenz` bedeutet, dass diese Teilchen real existieren und auch tatsächlich Teilchencharakter haben.

Answer (score 0):

naja.. ums mal anders zu sagen:
*physisch* für alles was du mit deinem Körper machst

und *physikalisch* für die verkopfte Beschreibung
eines idealen Abbildes der physischen Realität

Comment: Physisch ist aber oft auch was sie mit ihrem Körper macht!

Comment: Physikalische Modellierung hat nichts mit „ideal“ zu tun. Diese Interpretation ist völlig veraltet.

Comment: @Toscho zumindest die Schulphysik setzt immer eine ideale Umgebung vorraus in der Betrachtungen vorgenommen werden. Um eine 5-Seiten-Gleichung zu vermeiden werden kleinere Störaspekte (wie die Reibung und die Zusatzmasse durch Zusatzenergie) in einer physikalischen Beschreibung außen vor gelassen.

Comment: @Vogel612 Was du meinst sind Modelle. Die werden nicht nur in der Schulphysik, sondern in allen Naturwissenschaften verwendet. Die Umgebungen, die in diesen Modellen beschrieben werden, sind genauso „ideal“ wie die DDR „demokratisch“ war und das Sächsische Hochschulfreiheitsgesetz „Freiheiten“ beschreibt. Dieses veraltete Interpretation entstand aus Reibungsbetrachtungen bei Bewegungen. Pauschal wird gesagt, dass Reibungseffekte schlecht seien, weil sie die Bewegung behinderten. Ideal wäre also eine Bewegung ohne Reibung. Schon mal probiert, ein Auto ohne Reibung überhaupt zu beschleunigen?