# Zugangsschutz „physisch“ oder „physikalisch“

Tags: word-choice

Im Bezug auf die folgende Frage: [Wann sagt man "physikalisch" und wann "physisch"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8232/wann-sagt-man-physikalisch-und-wann-physisch)

**Ist der Zugangsschutz (zu Gebäuden) „physisch“ oder „physikalisch“?**

Ich lese immer „der physikalische Zugangsschutz …“, bin aber der Meinung, dass es ein physischer Zugangsschutz ist, weil er körperlich (durch eine Tür und ein Schloss) realisiert wird und nicht direkt auf der Physik basiert.

Comment: Zu einem "physischen Zugangsschutz" würde mir in erster Linie der Türsteher vor der Disko einfallen. Die sehen teilweise schon sehr "physisch" aus. ...und erst in zweiter Linie ein Zaun. Ein Zaun ist in meinen Augen ein "passiver Zugangsschutz"

Comment: Das mag sein. Mir geht es jedoch rein um die Unterscheidung von physisch und physikalisch.

Comment: Das ist meiner Meinung nach eine schlechte Übersetzung von "physical access", zu dem es im Englischen keine griffige Alternative gibt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Richtig, ein phyischer Zugangsschutz ist einfach ein materieller Schutz, wie z.B. ein hoher Zaun (im Gegensatz zu einem abstrakten Schutz wie z.B. ein Passwort). "Physisch" bezeichnet alle materiellen Dinge, nicht nur den menschlichen Körper.

Ein physikalischer Schutz wäre einer, der direkt mit physikalischen Prinzipien in Zusammenhang steht (vielleicht ein Foucauld'sches Pendel mit einer scharfen Klinge wie im Abenteuerfilm?)

Comment: "materiell" gefällt mir für einen Zaun sehr viel besser als "physisch" - Die Hauptverwendung für *physisch* ist in meinem Sprachgebrauch immer noch der menschliche Körper.

Comment: @tofro: Dein Sprachgebrauch ist aber nicht der Maßstab, sondern die deutsche Sprache. Materiell wird im Deutschen meist anders benutzt (materieller Vorteil). Physikalisch würde ich für eine Lichtschranke benutzen oder einen Bewegungsmelder.

Comment: @userunknown - Sorry, aber das hört sich für mich ein bisschen arrogant an, so als würdest du dir zutrauen, im Namen der deutschen Sprache zu sprechen.  Ich denke, mehr als *deinen eigenen Sprachgebrauch* hast du auch nicht zu bieten. Ansonsten wäre ich gespannt auf einen Beleg.

Comment: @tofro Ich kenne zumindest Ausschnitte des Sprachgebrauchs von Texten die ich lese und Gesprochenem, das ich höre. Du berufst Dich aber explizit auf Deinen Geschmack (gefällt mir) und Sprachgebrauch, und das ist hier nicht der Maßstab. Als Höflichkeitsformel ist ein solches Relativieren zwar gern gesehen, aber nicht hier, wo es darum geht, was richtig oder falsch ist, oder was stilistisch gut oder schlecht ist. Und was man persönlich findet, das sollte man, soweit es geht, raushalten. Dass niemand unfehlbar ist sollte allgemein bekannt sein.

Answer (score 2):

Im ersten Moment wollte ich dir zustimmen, doch hier ein Auszug aus dem [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/physikalisch) zu *physikalisch*:

1. die Physik betreffend; auf ihr, ihren Gesetzen beruhend, zu ihr gehörend
2. den Gesetzen, Erkenntnissen der Physik folgend, nach ihnen ablaufend, durch sie bestimmt
3. bestimmte Gesetze, Erkenntnisse der Physik nützend, anwendend; mithilfe bestimmter Gesetze, Erkenntnisse der Physik
4. **(veraltend) physisch**

Somit ist der Gebrauch von "physikalischer Zugangsschutz" tatsächlich noch korrekt - wird aber wohl irgendwann verschwinden.